# How do i mount sub folder contents to parent folder?

Tags: linux, mount

I have folder structure as below:

```
/files
/files/upload
```

I need to mount /files/upload to /files.

When user uploads files to

```
/files/upload
```

it should auto copy(sync/mount) uploaded file to base folder:

```
/files
```

.

Is it achievable using linux mount command ?

Thanks.

Comment: try `ln` but if you as on superuser, you could attract more attention.

Answer (score 1):

No. That would be pretty recursive.

You *can* however just have a separate process/daemon that moves/copies the files manually.

There is a mechanism in Linux called "fnotify" that would let a daemon register for filesystem events. i.e. it would tell the daemon whenever someone added a file into /file/upload - allowing you to initiate the copy/move.

But I'd be interesting in hearing more about why you are doing this before committing to a method.

Comment: /files contains many files and listing is slow while SFTP. So i created subfolder as bridge for the uplaod. If i can't make it with mount. how about rsync commands in cron job ?

Comment: I wouldn't rsync - because you just want to "move", not copy. Plus, you want to do *everything* in the folder. I don't know how time sensitive it is. Maybe just a cron job that fires every 5 minutes and does a "mv /files/upload/* /files/" ?

Comment: Thanks for advise, actually i just need to sync files, user might delete/edit files. can i use rsync for my case ?